# Double columns in a single div

Tags: css

I have a parent div with multiple child div so I need child divs placed two by two with each other:

```js
.parent ul li {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What should I do?

Comment: As in. You want the list items to be in pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just add float: left to your code.

```css
.parentDiv ul li {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.parent` in your CSS to `.parentDiv`. Then add `float: left;`. Here's a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/tegosovica/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your parent container a width. Then you can `float` your list items to the left.
Consider giving them a `height` or a `max-height` to always have them aligned properly. Also use `clear` on your parent container to prevent to have floating elements after your list.

html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
    width: 300px;
    clear: both;
}

.parent ul li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkofba1f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use float, inline-block or even flex:

```css
.parent ul, .parent li { /* reset and float minding */
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
.parent ul li {
  width: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
}
.parent ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
  background: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

inline-block:

```css
.parent ul,
.parent li {
  /* reset */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0.01px;
  /* avoid white space at screen from code indentation */
}
.parent ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
}
.parent ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

flex:

```css
.parent ul {
  /* reset */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.parent ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.parent ul li {
  width: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
}
.parent ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```